# Problem on getting JSON values in C# with an unrecognizable format

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to get the nodes inside a JSON request, this: https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=731490

But it's returning a format that a online json convert doesn't recognize and i can't get the values of nodes with C#.

Currently, i'm trying:

```
var gameInfo = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(gameInfo.ToString());
string header = (string)jObject.SelectToken("header_image");
```

But it return null for all properties. How do i access the header_image that is inside json object?

EDIT: JSON SAMPLE

```
{"731490":{"success":true,"data":{"type":"game","name":"Crash Bandicoot\u2122 N. Sane Trilogy","steam_appid":731490,"required_age":0,"is_free":false,"detailed_description":"Seu marsupial favorito, Crash Bandicoot\u2122, est\u00e1 de volta! Ele est\u00e1 aprimorado, inspirado e preparado para dan\u00e7ar na cole\u00e7\u00e3o de jogos da trilogia insana. Agora voc\u00ea pode jogar Crash Bandicoot como nunca antes. Gire, pule, golpeie e repita conforme voc\u00ea enfrentar as aventuras e os desafios \u00e9picos atrav\u00e9s dos tr\u00eas jogos que deram in\u00edcio a tudo, Crash Bandicoot\u2122, Crash Bandicoot\u2122 2: Cortex Strikes Back e Crash Bandicoot\u2122: Warped. Reviva todos os seus momentos favoritos de Crash em seu apogeu gr\u00e1fico em HD totalmente remasterizado e se prepare para colocar um CRASH nos seus golpes!<h2 class=\"bb_tag\">Crash Bandicoot\u2122 N. Sane Trilogy Stormy Ascent<\/h2><br>Vivencie a not\u00f3ria Stormy Ascent do jogo Crash Bandicoot original. Antes incompleta e nunca lan\u00e7ada, essa fase vai desafiar at\u00e9 os f\u00e3s mais veteranos do Crash! Ser\u00e1 que voc\u00ea consegue enfrentar degraus que se retraem, assistentes atiradores de frascos, p\u00e1ssaros ferozes, plataformas m\u00f3veis e espinhos de ferro? Baixe e jogue a fase Stormy Ascent!<h2 class=\"bb_tag\">Crash Bandicoot N. Sane Trilogy Future Tense<\/h2><br>Jogue a primeira fase NOVA para a trilogia original em quase 20 anos. Inspirado na fase &quot;Waterfall&quot; do primeiro jogo de Crash Bandicoot, Future Tense apresenta v\u00e1rios quebra-cabe\u00e7as da fase original ambientados em um cen\u00e1rio futurista de Crash Bandicoot 3: Warped. Descubra um novo n\u00edvel de dificuldade para Crash Bandicoot N. Sane Trilogy desviando de foguetes, destruindo rob\u00f4s e pulando lasers enquanto voc\u00ea sobe por um arranha-c\u00e9u enorme e futurista.","about_the_game":"Seu marsupial favorito, Crash Bandicoot\u2122, est\u00e1 de volta! Ele est\u00e1 aprimorado, inspirado e preparado para dan\u00e7ar na cole\u00e7\u00e3o de jogos da trilogia insana. Agora voc\u00ea pode jogar Crash Bandicoot como nunca antes. Gire, pule, golpeie e repita conforme voc\u00ea enfrentar as aventuras e os desafios \u00e9picos atrav\u00e9s dos tr\u00eas jogos que deram in\u00edcio a tudo, Crash Bandicoot\u2122, Crash Bandicoot\u2122 2: Cortex Strikes Back e Crash Bandicoot\u2122: Warped. Reviva todos os seus momentos favoritos de Crash em seu apogeu gr\u00e1fico em HD totalmente remasterizado e se prepare para colocar um CRASH nos seus golpes!<h2 class=\"bb_tag\">Crash Bandicoot\u2122 N. Sane Trilogy Stormy Ascent<\/h2><br>Vivencie a not\u00f3ria Stormy Ascent do jogo Crash Bandicoot original. Antes incompleta e nunca lan\u00e7ada, essa fase vai desafiar at\u00e9 os f\u00e3s mais veteranos do Crash! Ser\u00e1 que voc\u00ea consegue enfrentar degraus que se retraem, assistentes atiradores de frascos, p\u00e1ssaros ferozes, plataformas m\u00f3veis e espinhos de ferro? Baixe e jogue a fase Stormy Ascent!<h2 class=\"bb_tag\">Crash Bandicoot N. Sane Trilogy Future Tense<\/h2><br>Jogue a primeira fase NOVA para a trilogia original em quase 20 anos. Inspirado na fase &quot;Waterfall&quot; do primeiro jogo de Crash Bandicoot, Future Tense apresenta v\u00e1rios quebra-cabe\u00e7as da fase original ambientados em um cen\u00e1rio futurista de Crash Bandicoot 3: Warped. Descubra um novo n\u00edvel de dificuldade para Crash Bandicoot N. Sane Trilogy desviando de foguetes, destruindo rob\u00f4s e pulando lasers enquanto voc\u00ea sobe por um arranha-c\u00e9u enorme e futurista.","short_description":"Seu marsupial favorito, Crash Bandicoot\u00ae, voltou! Aprimorado, inspirado e pronto para dan\u00e7ar nessa trilogia insana. Reviva seus momentos favoritos em Crash Bandicoot\u2122, Crash Bandicoot\u2122 2: Cortex Strikes Back e Crash Bandicoot\u2122 3: Warped, agora com gr\u00e1ficos HD completamente remasterizados!","supported_languages":"Ingl\u00eas<strong>*<\/strong>, Franc\u00eas<strong>*<\/strong>, Italiano<strong>*<\/strong>, Alem\u00e3o<strong>*<\/strong>, Espanhol (Espanha)<strong>*<\/strong><br><strong>*<\/strong>idiomas com suporte total de \u00e1udio","header_image":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/header.jpg?t=1568841571","website":"https:\/\/www.crashbandicoot.com","pc_requirements":{"minimum":"<strong>M\u00ednimos:<\/strong><br><ul class=\"bb_ul\"><li><strong>SO:<\/strong> Windows 7<br><\/li><li><strong>Processador:<\/strong> Intel Core i5-750 @ 2.67GHz | AMD Phenom II X4 965 @ 3.4GHz<br><\/li><li><strong>Mem\u00f3ria:<\/strong> 8 GB de RAM<br><\/li><li><strong>Placa de v\u00eddeo:<\/strong> NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 2GB | AMD Radeon HD 7850 2GB<br><\/li><li><strong>DirectX:<\/strong> Vers\u00e3o 9.0c<br><\/li><li><strong>Armazenamento:<\/strong> 30 GB de espa\u00e7o dispon\u00edvel<br><\/li><li><strong>Placa de som:<\/strong> DirectX 9.0c Compatible<\/li><\/ul>"},"mac_requirements":[],"linux_requirements":[],"legal_notice":"\u00a9 2018 Activision Publishing, Inc. ACTIVISION e CRASH BANDICOOT s\u00e3o marcas comerciais da Activision Publishing, Inc.","developers":["Vicarious Visions","Iron Galaxy"],"publishers":["Activision"],"price_overview":{"currency":"BRL","initial":15000,"final":15000,"discount_percent":0,"initial_formatted":"","final_formatted":"R$ 150,00"},"packages":[213423],"package_groups":[{"name":"default","title":"Comprar Crash Bandicoot\u2122 N. Sane Trilogy","description":"","selection_text":"Selecione uma op\u00e7\u00e3o de compra","save_text":"","display_type":0,"is_recurring_subscription":"false","subs":[{"packageid":213423,"percent_savings_text":"","percent_savings":0,"option_text":"Crash Bandicoot\u2122 N. Sane Trilogy - R$ 150,00","option_description":"","can_get_free_license":"0","is_free_license":false,"price_in_cents_with_discount":15000}]}],"platforms":{"windows":true,"mac":false,"linux":false},"categories":[{"id":2,"description":"Um jogador"},{"id":22,"description":"Conquistas Steam"},{"id":29,"description":"Cartas Colecion\u00e1veis Steam"},{"id":18,"description":"Compatibilidade parcial com controle"},{"id":23,"description":"Nuvem Steam"},{"id":41,"description":"Remote Play no celular"},{"id":42,"description":"Remote Play no tablet"}],"genres":[{"id":"1","description":"A\u00e7\u00e3o"}],"screenshots":[{"id":0,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_66d4bf28161b1c7a5a78f579bcea05a0785f2c50.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_66d4bf28161b1c7a5a78f579bcea05a0785f2c50.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":1,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_931f13ad19753ac5d491bc55e31ec9e2181ca637.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_931f13ad19753ac5d491bc55e31ec9e2181ca637.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":2,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_312f4dbd137af1b36c3572aaa79349db6dd841a2.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_312f4dbd137af1b36c3572aaa79349db6dd841a2.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":3,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_76889923300ce3a20d7a57b3b42d9f4d549106f3.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_76889923300ce3a20d7a57b3b42d9f4d549106f3.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":4,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_73fcdfb2150a35d1bbe824581555d39f57c31234.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_73fcdfb2150a35d1bbe824581555d39f57c31234.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":5,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_c2439741a40a81e4772412b4a92866aa1f188f2f.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_c2439741a40a81e4772412b4a92866aa1f188f2f.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":6,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_ec680b2e1d6314aeab89627fe7e3118f6b884026.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_ec680b2e1d6314aeab89627fe7e3118f6b884026.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":7,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_6df148c304cc75e3e6a064f74897b098b93e7999.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_6df148c304cc75e3e6a064f74897b098b93e7999.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":8,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_106c1ce7c8fbfec289d9005385209c592cd8a03e.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_106c1ce7c8fbfec289d9005385209c592cd8a03e.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":9,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_fad459eb04408dd926de3b789c8bc6d13bf855c0.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_fad459eb04408dd926de3b789c8bc6d13bf855c0.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":10,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_d02c73a64ac53da19d336c64821e6e66f94aa912.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_d02c73a64ac53da19d336c64821e6e66f94aa912.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":11,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_5570ddf9fd565900d83b5a89099f6eecc07780cd.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_5570ddf9fd565900d83b5a89099f6eecc07780cd.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":12,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_1a5bd0956c774afcadb1474f5fed2085715f2987.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_1a5bd0956c774afcadb1474f5fed2085715f2987.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":13,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_52a34a9b5105ae4bd77f4a15e735282f000dd239.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_52a34a9b5105ae4bd77f4a15e735282f000dd239.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":14,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_c65647d67a01dd01ba99fbfd9a46bc5220a8c5cf.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_c65647d67a01dd01ba99fbfd9a46bc5220a8c5cf.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":15,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_bf301672eede469605ef823057cba1eb3b845f12.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_bf301672eede469605ef823057cba1eb3b845f12.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":16,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_1658e70049a0de5ec46606696719771c5c72842a.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_1658e70049a0de5ec46606696719771c5c72842a.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":17,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_54e91fcc8981a7464b7e58d9b7836c4735f03333.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_54e91fcc8981a7464b7e58d9b7836c4735f03333.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"},{"id":18,"path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_1fd131fc50ca8f4a849de5eec97260b88a5865c6.600x338.jpg?t=1568841571","path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/ss_1fd131fc50ca8f4a849de5eec97260b88a5865c6.1920x1080.jpg?t=1568841571"}],"movies":[{"id":256720063,"name":"Crash Bandicoot\u2122 N. Sane Trilogy - Future Tense Launch Trailer","thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/256720063\/movie.293x165.jpg?t=1529112507","webm":{"480":"http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/256720063\/movie480.webm?t=1529112507","max":"http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/256720063\/movie_max.webm?t=1529112507"},"highlight":true},{"id":256711002,"name":"Crash Bandicoot\u2122 N. Sane Trilogy - Better With Crashitude Gameplay Trailer","thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/256711002\/movie.293x165.jpg?t=1520629752","webm":{"480":"http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/256711002\/movie480.webm?t=1520629752","max":"http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/256711002\/movie_max.webm?t=1520629752"},"highlight":true}],"recommendations":{"total":4662},"achievements":{"total":74,"highlighted":[{"name":"C1 | Papu Popped","path":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/731490\/ebf5292157d9da9b5a32148986275a9d75e3c485.jpg"},{"name":"C1 | Ripper Ruined","path":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/731490\/29032c985b872eca1a55963e5b983f1468e1d992.jpg"},{"name":"C1 | Spin Doctor","path":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/731490\/cafabcaa86bd99c7ec49d00e86433eb128fbcd21.jpg"},{"name":"C1 | I Meant To Do That!","path":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/731490\/8e2ad82dafb8919bb05a8b878476daba9008c2fc.jpg"},{"name":"C1 | That's What Those Do!","path":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/731490\/14e3928a27da6ad10a0975b86ea911c2cb18aa1f.jpg"},{"name":"C1 | Catch Me If You Can!","path":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/731490\/25b9aade232f9ee39c071d03022793d8186e3842.jpg"},{"name":"C1 | Feeeed Meeeee!","path":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/731490\/c0d6ffe87c82274914211c6f393c5bb59417a066.jpg"},{"name":"C1 | The Box That Broke the Bandicoot's Back","path":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/731490\/f244e975d9dbe6610228ac6f4bbb07bf5a1b4752.jpg"},{"name":"C1 | Koala Konked","path":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/731490\/c4c275da3ca63c62d5e26f0947d5fc64e51f9ff1.jpg"},{"name":"C1 | Pinstripe Patooey","path":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/731490\/bd2cdeaad120e2b2b16f37f94e05db8b9acb83d5.jpg"}]},"release_date":{"coming_soon":false,"date":"29\/jun\/2018"},"support_info":{"url":"https:\/\/support.activision.com\/","email":""},"background":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/731490\/page_bg_generated_v6b.jpg?t=1568841571","content_descriptors":{"ids":[],"notes":null}}}}
```

Comment: Include the json sample in your post please.

Comment: Sample Included.

Comment: Well i went to https://jsonlint.com/ posted the output from your link and it shows as valid json... so i am not sure what you mean.  Also your json seems to have HTML portions in it. so you might want to html decode the response after the fact.

Comment: I would recommend that you create an actual model.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro try this json on json2csharp.com, it don't work properly.

Comment: Bazz I just made it work.... All I did was go to https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=731490  and copy paste the output to json2csharp.com.... I was able to generate a model... Modified it slightly and it worked just fine.

Comment: The only thing I changed was the invalid type a little bit.  And added an attribute to the property to change the name.... Check my answer it works.

Comment: I changed my answer to make it dynamic. It now supports multiple "apps" by ID ... so you could have multiple results in your json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a strongly typed model.

This is what I did.

1. Tested the JSON at https://jsonlint.com/ to make sure it is valid.
2. Used http://json2csharp.com/ to generate a strongly typed model.

I was able to read the entire contents of the JSON in this link: https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=731490

This is how made it work:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

The model I used is this:
Notice that the RootObject inherits from

```
Dictionary<string, AppRoot>
```

Notice also that the name of the "invalid" type is now AppRoot.

This will now support multiple Apps by ID

```
  public class RootObject: Dictionary<string, AppRoot>
  {

  }

  public class AppRoot
  {
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
  }

  public class PcRequirements
  {
    public string minimum { get; set; }
  }

  public class PriceOverview
  {
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public int initial { get; set; }
    public int final { get; set; }
    public int discount_percent { get; set; }
    public string initial_formatted { get; set; }
    public string final_formatted { get; set; }
  }

  public class Sub
  {
    public int packageid { get; set; }
    public string percent_savings_text { get; set; }
    public int percent_savings { get; set; }
    public string option_text { get; set; }
    public string option_description { get; set; }
    public string can_get_free_license { get; set; }
    public bool is_free_license { get; set; }
    public int price_in_cents_with_discount { get; set; }
  }

  public class PackageGroup
  {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string selection_text { get; set; }
    public string save_text { get; set; }
    public int display_type { get; set; }
    public string is_recurring_subscription { get; set; }
    public List<Sub> subs { get; set; }
  }

  public class Platforms
  {
    public bool windows { get; set; }
    public bool mac { get; set; }
    public bool linux { get; set; }
  }

  public class Category
  {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
  }

  public class Genre
  {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
  }

  public class Screenshot
  {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string path_thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string path_full { get; set; }
  }

  public class Webm
  {
    public string __invalid_name__480 { get; set; }
    public string max { get; set; }
  }

  public class Movie
  {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public Webm webm { get; set; }
    public bool highlight { get; set; }
  }

  public class Recommendations
  {
    public int total { get; set; }
  }

  public class Highlighted
  {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
  }

  public class Achievements
  {
    public int total { get; set; }
    public List<Highlighted> highlighted { get; set; }
  }

  public class ReleaseDate
  {
    public bool coming_soon { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
  }

  public class SupportInfo
  {
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
  }

  public class ContentDescriptors
  {
    public List<object> ids { get; set; }
    public object notes { get; set; }
  }

  public class Data
  {
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int steam_appid { get; set; }
    public int required_age { get; set; }
    public bool is_free { get; set; }
    public string detailed_description { get; set; }
    public string about_the_game { get; set; }
    public string short_description { get; set; }
    public string supported_languages { get; set; }
    public string header_image { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public PcRequirements pc_requirements { get; set; }
    public List<object> mac_requirements { get; set; }
    public List<object> linux_requirements { get; set; }
    public string legal_notice { get; set; }
    public List<string> developers { get; set; }
    public List<string> publishers { get; set; }
    public PriceOverview price_overview { get; set; }
    public List<int> packages { get; set; }
    public List<PackageGroup> package_groups { get; set; }
    public Platforms platforms { get; set; }
    public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
    public List<Genre> genres { get; set; }
    public List<Screenshot> screenshots { get; set; }
    public List<Movie> movies { get; set; }
    public Recommendations recommendations { get; set; }
    public Achievements achievements { get; set; }
    public ReleaseDate release_date { get; set; }
    public SupportInfo support_info { get; set; }
    public string background { get; set; }
    public ContentDescriptors content_descriptors { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: The `RootObject` class can instead be replaced by a `Dictionary<string, Type__7314890>`.

That would allow the model to support _any_ App ID.

Comment: @RJ yes i agree

Comment: Well @JonathanAlfaro this worked fine, but only for appID: 731490, if i try another, like 546560, then it don't works, is there a way to set this jsonproperty dinamically?

Comment: @Bazz yes sure.... I will change my answer to be dynamic.  Please mark as answered if it works for you

Comment: It Worked. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Bazz you got it!

Answer (score 1):

`JObject.SelectToken` expects a path to a particular token. It doesn't traverse the object to find anything with a matching name.

Looking at the object, the root object seems to have a single property with the key being the app id. That in turn has two properties, `success` and `data`, with `data` containing the actual info you seek.

The following works for me:

```cs
using var client = new HttpClient();
var text = await client.GetStringAsync("https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=731490");
var jo = JObject.Parse(text);
var header = (string)jo.SelectToken("731490.data.header_image");
```

Having a strongly typed model would make this easier in the long run, though.

Comment: How do i type if the number, 731490 is dynamic? i mean, the number is an app id, an if i send another app id, the number changes, so if i try to type this json on json2csharp.com it gives me a error

Comment: `appId + ".data.header_image"`, or `$"{appId}.data.header_image"`, or `jo[appId].SelectToken("data.header_image")`, or...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked, but then i had another problem, but your answer worked, and thank you so much for replying.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must await your method to reduce thread locks

```
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Then you could try this

```
var gameInfo = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(content);
string header = gameInfo["731490"]["data"]["header_image"];
```

To ignore first dynamic element:

```
gameInfo.Properties().Children().ToList()[0]["data"]["header_image"]
```

Comment: Your answer worked, but then i had another need, but your answer is correct. Thank you so much for replying my post.